# Is there any way to buy Google Play money in Taiwan without a credit card?

Tags: cellphones, taiwan, payment, phone-networks

I've seen Google Play "gift cards" on sale in convenience stores in several nearby countries, but for some reason I don't see them in Taiwan. Convenience store displays show cards for Apple's App Store, LINE, XBOX, PlayStation etc. but there is a notable absence of "The Google".

I then read that the largest phone company [Chunghwa Telecom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunghwa_Telecom) lets people put Google Play on their monthly telephone bill, but a visit to two offices was unsuccessful; both times I was told that they don't extend this particular service to foreigners.

Are there any other options other than credit cards? (I don't use them myself) I see advertisements for Google Play money in online shopping venues and I can have a friend help me buy those, but I don't know if there are "regional specifications" that would somehow make them unusable to buy more storage space for email or buying apps.

**note:** My google account was started a long time ago in the US if that makes a difference.

---

Some random examples of possible online sites selling cards, but I don't know if these will somehow also end up being restricted some way for use by foreigners in Taiwan (I've never done anything like this before)

- https://www.ruten.com.tw/item/show?21305120932356
- https://e7fun-tw.translate.goog/zh/google-play?_x_tr_sl=zh-CN&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

---

Photos of two
different convenience store "gift card" racks showing Apple's App Store, LINE, XBOX, PlayStation cards but no Google Play:

[image: Apple's App Store, LINE, XBOX, PlayStation but no Google Play gift cards in seven-elevens]

Comment: Are there other applicable tags that I missed?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Google Play giftcards in Taiwan and if you have a Taiwanese account it will not support payment using giftcards.

Comment: @xngtng what does "Taiwanese account" mean? I started my google account a long time ago in the US. (I'll add that back into the question as well)

Comment: see [google's help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en) re what country your google play account is based in, and how to change it, and the limits on that

Comment: @mlc I see, so there are two location-associated issues; one is the country of the account and the other is the country where you're trying to obtain a Google Play gift card to add money to it.